# Android ListView Expand Item List

Tags: android, listview

i am creating a listview in an android activity, and i want to expand the currently selected item to display more details,

for example, contact list display only first and last name, and when select contact item, expand the selected item to display more details for that contact like first name, last name, mail, telephone numbers...etc

Answer (score 1):

Please Used Expandable List-view for that.

please refer http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).